# INPUT fields and SUBMIT button are not "disabled". Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a registration form using the `formik` library.

**I want to implement this:**
If submitting the form, the `submit` button and `input` fields should be `disabled`.

To achieve that, I did as follows:

- destructured `isSubmitting` and `setSubmitting`,
- `setSubmitting(true)` in `onSubmit`,
- `disabled: isSubmitting` within `inputProps` of `FFInput` Component, and
- I also wrote `disabled={isSubmitting}` in submit button.

**But still `disabled` don't work.
How to fix this problem?**

Code in codesandbox: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-sea-zkix7
For some reason another error was added in the sandbox, it is not present in the text editor

Note: I've commented within the code (below) to highlight these are relevant changes.

```js
const FForm = () => { 
  const {
    // ...
    handleSubmit, handleChange, isSubmitting, setSubmitting  // destructured here:
  } = useFormik({                 
    initialValues: { username: '', email: '', password: '', confirm_password: '' },
    validateOnBlur: false,
    validateOnchange: false,
    validationSchema: yup.object().shape({...}),   
    onSubmit: async (formValues) => {
       console.log('submit', formValues);
       setSubmitting(true)                    //disabled
       try {
         const res = api('posts', { method:'POST', body: JSON.stringify(formValues) });
         console.log('Result!',res);
       } catch(e) {
         console.error(e);
       } finally {
         setSubmitting(false);
       }
      },    
    });

   return (
     <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>   
       <FFInput
         label="username"
         id="username" 
         inputProps={{
           //...
           disabled: isSubmitting,                     //disabled
         }}
         error={errors.username}
       />
      <FFInput
         label="email"
         id="email" 
         inputProps={{
           // ...
           disabled: isSubmitting,                     //disabled
         }}
         error={errors.email}
       />
       <FFInput
         label="password"
         id="password" 
         inputProps={{
           // ...
           disabled: isSubmitting,                      //disabled
         }}
         error={errors.password}
       />
       <FFInput
         label="Confirm password"
         id="confirm_password" 
         inputProps={{
           // ...
           disabled: isSubmitting,                      //disabled
         }}
         error={errors.confirm_password}
       />
       <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>   //  disabled
         Submit Form
       </button>       
   </form>
   );
};

export default FForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formik gives you a bunch of tools as second parameter of your onSubmit handler, you get `setSubmitting` with that and then use that `setSubmitting` function to control the submitting state like this:

```js
onSubmit: async (formValues, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log('submit', formValues);
    setSubmitting(true)                    //disabled
    try {
        const res = api('posts', { method:'POST', body: JSON.stringify(formValues)});
        console.log('Result!',res);
    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        setSubmitting(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: also not disabled, can you fix it in my sandbox? and write a link to a new sandbox?

Comment: I don't have access to your api code in codesandbox.io, I'll do a hack with Promise to make delay

Comment: Here you go:
https://codesandbox.io/s/green-fire-tlfgi?file=/src/components/FForm/FForm.js

Let me know if it works or not :)